# The relationship between the determinant & the integration?

Tags: integration, matrices

I'm curious to know the relationship between the determinant and the integration by using the area of the square
Let's say we have the following matrix.
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \\
det(A) = 2*2 - 0*0 = 4
$$

Now, the funciton is $f(x) = a$ where $a$ is the length of the square's sides. So, 
$$
f(x) = \int^2_0 a dx = 2*x \rvert^{2}_{0} = 4
$$

where $a = 2$
Is there any article handles this topic? I mean the similarities between the determinant and the integration?
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could help you along the way
https://aimsciences.org/journals/pdfs.jsp?paperID=1224&mode=full

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers - they are susceptible to link-rot, and a self-contained response is best. Can you summarize the content of your link here?

Comment: Well he asked specifically for articles so I think it's valid in this case? I'll keep it in mind next time though ;)

Answer (score 0):

We can use A two-dimensional linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ of the form

\begin{equation*}
T(x,y) =\left(ax+by,cx+dy\right) =\begin{bmatrix}
a & b  \\[3pt]
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x  \\[3pt]
y \\
\end{bmatrix}=A\begin{bmatrix}
x  \\[3pt]
y \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

We will view $ T $ as mapping objects from the xy-plane onto an $ x'y'$-plane: $ (x',y')=T(x,y) $. The geometric properties of this mapping will be reflected in the determinant of the matrix $ A $ associated with $ T $. In fact, the absolute value of the determinant of a $ 2×2 $ matrix gives the area of the parallelogram spanned by the vectors $ (a,b) $ and $(c,d)$.

Then the reason for getting a factor of $ 4 $  is due to the fact that determinants of $ 2×2 $ matrices reflect area of the parallelogram define by $[0,2]$x$[0,2]$.

But the area of parallelogram can be express as 
\begin{align}
 \mathrm{Area}(P) &= \mid b-a\mid \mid d-c \mid\\
     &= \int_0^{r} 2 \mid d-c \mid   dt
\end{align}
Then if we consider the function $ f(x)= \mid d-c \mid $ then in this case $ d=2 $ and $ c=0 $.